# date_range won't include last date of interval for custom frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date-range

I want to create a date vector with a given fixed spacing depending on the frequency I choose. So far, this is what I got:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date, timedelta
    
def getDates(sD, eD, f):
    # creating the datetime object to later on make the date vector
    sD = dt.datetime.strptime(sD, '%m/%d/%Y')
    eD = dt.datetime.strptime(eD, '%m/%d/%Y')
    sd_t = date(sD.year,sD.month,sD.day)   # start date
    ed_t = date(eD.year,eD.month,eD.day)   # end date
    # we hardcode a frequency dictionary for the frequencies and spacing that 
    # date vectors are going to have.
    freqDict = {'1h':'40D', '4h':'162D', '1d':'1000D'}
    dateVector = pd.date_range(sd_t, ed_t, freq = freqDict[f])
    return dateVector
```

As you can see, I have only 3 frequencies I'm interested in. And the spacing between them works well, I have to play with API limitations and the limit I set up for requests is 1000. This is why I chose these custom spacings between dates, in order to allow a good amount of data points as possible according to the frequency and the API request limitations for which these dates are meant.

Unfortunately, I can't get the final date on the dateVector for some cases. If run this function with these inputs:

```
getDates('01/01/2020', '01/01/2021', '4h')
```

I get this outcome, which is missing the final date on the array ('01/01/2021'):

```
0   2020-01-01
1   2020-06-11
2   2020-11-20
```

I thought of using the `closed =`  parameter, but it didn't get me where I wanted.

A workaround I thought of consists of using `periods` instead of `freq`, and dynamically computing the periods according to the distance (in terms of days) between the start date and the end date. But I would like to know if I can make `date_range` work in my favor without having to write such a routine.

Comment: What do you mean *missing the array on the final date* ?

Comment: Thanks for the observation @Psidom, I edited the post.

Comment: That's not how `date_range` works. If you simply need to include the final date, you can just append it to the `dateVector`.

Comment: @Psidom hmmmm, I see. Just wanted to explore other options, but I guess it is easier to transform the outcome into a list, change the datetime objects to just dates, then make a conditional append to that array if the end date is not included.